# Can't find method for explicit form of bivariate recurrence relation

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

Given:

$a_{m,0}=0,$

$0<q,r<p<1,$

$p+q+r=1,$

$D_0,D_1>0,$

and an integer $k > 0$, s.t. $k*q<1;$

does there exist an explicit form for the the following recurrence relation:

$a_{m,n} = p*a_{m,n-1} + q*a_{m,n+k} + r*a_{m+1,n} + D_0*m +D_1$?

If so, what is it?

Comment: The problematic term for me is $q*a_{m,n+k}$, I can't seem to get very far with it with iterative substitution, lag operators, or even generating functions.

Comment: I can maybe make some progress with the generating functions if i include indicator functions in some of the terms...is this common? anyone have a reference for such things?